# client side data annotation is not working on partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

i am facing a general problem inside my asp.net mvc3 application, that **all the partial views will not show client side validation errors that i define using data annotations**,, for example i have defined the following data annotations:-

```
public class Country_Validation
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required.")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage="{0} is too long.",MinimumLength=1)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

and i have the following action method that will be called using `ajax.beginform` and which will then returns a partial view to create a new `Country` object:-

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Country c = new Country();
            return PartialView("_Create",c);
        }
```

which will return the following `_Create` partial view:-

```
@model Medical.Models.Country

<div id = "partialWrapper">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Country", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "Countrytable",
    OnSuccess = "clearform"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Country</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
        <strong>Country Name:-</strong>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </fieldset>
 }
 </div>
```

but if i try to add a new `country` object while leaving the `Description` field empty, then no client side validation error will be shown , while if i return a regular view (not partial) then all the client side validation error will work fine?
So what might be the problem?
BR

Answer (score 3):

I came across something similar recently. The solution was to add the following to my partial view(s) right before my content (but after  I declared my model type and any using statements):

```
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();   
}
```

You may also want to take a look at the following link which deals with the javascript side of enabling validation for newly added content:

http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Comment: i came back to this issue , but adding iewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();   is not working.